# Jboss can't start web app and no errors in log

Tags: jsf, jboss, jsf-1.2

I'm trying to get a web app up and running on jboss 5 in eclipse and i'm not getting any errors in the log and when i hit `http://localhost:8080/WebDataViewer`, i just get the default http 404 error page.

When i hit `http://localhost:8080/` i get the default jboss page with some links on it.

I've not worked with jboss before, but can anyone help figure out how i can access my app or how i can troubleshoot this?

```
10:07:39,706 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting JBoss (Microcontainer)...
10:07:39,707 INFO  [ServerImpl] Release ID: JBoss [The Oracle] 5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221634)
10:07:39,707 INFO  [ServerImpl] Bootstrap URL: null
10:07:39,707 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home Dir: C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA
10:07:39,708 INFO  [ServerImpl] Home URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/
10:07:39,708 INFO  [ServerImpl] Library URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/lib/
10:07:39,708 INFO  [ServerImpl] Patch URL: null
10:07:39,708 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Base URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/common/
10:07:39,708 INFO  [ServerImpl] Common Library URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/common/lib/
10:07:39,709 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Name: default
10:07:39,709 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base Dir: C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server
10:07:39,709 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Base URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/
10:07:39,709 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Config URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/conf/
10:07:39,709 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home Dir: C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default
10:07:39,709 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Home URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/
10:07:39,709 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Data Dir: C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\data
10:07:39,709 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Library URL: file:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/lib/
10:07:39,710 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Log Dir: C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\log
10:07:39,710 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Native Dir: C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\tmp\native
10:07:39,710 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Dir: C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\tmp
10:07:39,710 INFO  [ServerImpl] Server Temp Deploy Dir: C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\tmp\deploy
10:07:40,279 INFO  [ServerImpl] Starting Microcontainer, bootstrapURL=file:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/conf/bootstrap.xml
10:07:40,898 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Initializing VFSCache [org.jboss.virtual.plugins.cache.CombinedVFSCache]
10:07:40,900 INFO  [VFSCacheFactory] Using VFSCache [CombinedVFSCache[real-cache: null]]
10:07:41,132 INFO  [CopyMechanism] VFS temp dir: C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\tmp
10:07:41,133 INFO  [ZipEntryContext] VFS force nested jars copy-mode is enabled.
10:07:42,399 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java version: 1.6.0_35,Sun Microsystems Inc.
10:07:42,399 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10)
10:07:42,399 INFO  [ServerInfo] Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 20.10-b01,Sun Microsystems Inc.
10:07:42,399 INFO  [ServerInfo] OS-System: Windows 7 6.1,amd64
10:07:42,399 INFO  [ServerInfo] VM arguments: -Dprogram.name=run.bat -Xms128m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 
10:07:42,425 INFO  [JMXKernel] Legacy JMX core initialized
10:07:44,183 INFO  [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Loading profile: ProfileKey@2ee634bf[domain=default, server=default, name=default]
10:07:45,435 INFO  [WebService] Using RMI server codebase: http://127.0.0.1:8083/
10:07:50,839 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] JBoss Web Services - Stack Native Core
10:07:50,839 INFO  [NativeServerConfig] 3.1.2.GA
10:07:51,473 INFO  [AttributeCallbackItem] Owner callback not implemented.
10:07:52,334 INFO  [LogNotificationListener] Adding notification listener for logging mbean "jboss.system:service=Logging,type=Log4jService" to server org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl@5de82b72[ defaultDomain='jboss' ]
10:08:06,536 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@1493227242{vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/profileservice-secured.jar/}
10:08:06,536 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@1493227242{vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/profileservice-secured.jar/}
10:08:06,537 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@1493227242{vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/profileservice-secured.jar/}
10:08:06,537 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@1493227242{vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/profileservice-secured.jar/}
10:08:08,928 INFO  [JMXConnectorServerService] JMX Connector server: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:1090/jmxconnector
10:08:09,029 INFO  [MailService] Mail Service bound to java:/Mail
10:08:11,006 WARN  [JBossASSecurityMetadataStore] WARNING! POTENTIAL SECURITY RISK. It has been detected that the MessageSucker component which sucks messages from one node to another has not had its password changed from the installation default. Please see the JBoss Messaging user guide for instructions on how to do this.
10:08:11,020 WARN  [AnnotationCreator] No ClassLoader provided, using TCCL: org.jboss.managed.api.annotation.ManagementComponent
10:08:11,073 WARN  [AnnotationCreator] No ClassLoader provided, using TCCL: org.jboss.managed.api.annotation.ManagementComponent
10:08:11,111 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version - tag:JBOSSTS_4_6_1_GA) - JBoss Inc.
10:08:11,111 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Setting up property manager MBean and JMX layer
10:08:11,312 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Initializing recovery manager
10:08:11,436 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Recovery manager configured
10:08:11,436 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Binding TransactionManager JNDI Reference
10:08:11,457 INFO  [TransactionManagerService] Starting transaction recovery manager
10:08:12,016 INFO  [AprLifecycleListener] The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;c:\program files\apache-maven-3.0.x\bin;C:\Ruby192\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\sybase15_0_7\OCS-15_0\bin;C:\sybase15_0_7\OCS-15_0\dll;C:\sybase15_0_7\OCS-15_0\lib3p;C:\sybase15_0_7\DataAccess\ADONET\dll;C:\sybase15_0_7\DataAccess\ODBC\dll;C:\sybase15_0_7\DataAccess\OLEDB\dll;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;c:\Program Files\Stellent\IBPM;C:\PROGRA~2\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\PROGRA~2\IBM\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\PROGRA~2\IBM\SQLLIB\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin;C:\Oracle_Instant_Client(32bit)\instantclient_11_2;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\eclipse;;.
10:08:12,087 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
10:08:12,089 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
10:08:12,122 INFO  [StandardService] Starting service jboss.web
10:08:12,130 INFO  [StandardEngine] Starting Servlet Engine: JBoss Web/2.1.3.GA
10:08:12,235 INFO  [Catalina] Server startup in 145 ms
10:08:12,258 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/web-console
10:08:12,993 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/jbossws
10:08:13,068 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/invoker
10:08:13,242 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jboss-local-jdbc.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
10:08:13,285 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jboss-xa-jdbc.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
10:08:13,310 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/jms-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
10:08:13,324 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/mail-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
10:08:13,353 INFO  [RARDeployment] Required license terms exist, view vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/quartz-ra.rar/META-INF/ra.xml
10:08:13,422 INFO  [SimpleThreadPool] Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
10:08:13,442 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Quartz Scheduler v.1.5.2 created.
10:08:13,445 INFO  [RAMJobStore] RAMJobStore initialized.
10:08:13,446 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
10:08:13,446 INFO  [StdSchedulerFactory] Quartz scheduler version: 1.5.2
10:08:13,446 INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
10:08:13,769 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=DefaultDS' to JNDI name 'java:DefaultDS'
10:08:14,145 INFO  [ServerPeer] JBoss Messaging 1.4.3.GA server [0] started
10:08:14,220 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/ExpiryQueue] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
10:08:14,269 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] Connector bisocket://127.0.0.1:4457 has leasing enabled, lease period 10000 milliseconds
10:08:14,269 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory@4bb8e77c started
10:08:14,271 INFO  [QueueService] Queue[/queue/DLQ] started, fullSize=200000, pageSize=2000, downCacheSize=2000
10:08:14,272 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] Connector bisocket://127.0.0.1:4457 has leasing enabled, lease period 10000 milliseconds
10:08:14,272 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory@28062593 started
10:08:14,272 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryJNDIMapper] supportsFailover attribute is true on connection factory: jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ClusteredConnectionFactory but post office is non clustered. So connection factory will *not* support failover
10:08:14,282 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryJNDIMapper] supportsLoadBalancing attribute is true on connection factory: jboss.messaging.connectionfactory:service=ClusteredConnectionFactory but post office is non clustered. So connection factory will *not* support load balancing
10:08:14,283 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] Connector bisocket://127.0.0.1:4457 has leasing enabled, lease period 10000 milliseconds
10:08:14,283 INFO  [ConnectionFactory] org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory@30726eca started
10:08:14,419 INFO  [ConnectionFactoryBindingService] Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=ConnectionFactoryBinding,name=JmsXA' to JNDI name 'java:JmsXA'
10:08:14,705 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Created KernelDeployment for: profileservice-secured.jar
10:08:14,712 INFO  [JBossASKernel] installing bean: jboss.j2ee:jar=profileservice-secured.jar,name=SecureProfileService,service=EJB3
10:08:14,712 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   with dependencies:
10:08:14,712 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and demands:
10:08:14,712 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jndi:SecureManagementView/remote-org.jboss.deployers.spi.management.ManagementView
10:08:14,712 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService
10:08:14,713 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and supplies:
10:08:14,713 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  Class:org.jboss.profileservice.spi.ProfileService
10:08:14,713 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jndi:SecureProfileService/remote
10:08:14,713 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jndi:SecureProfileService/remote-org.jboss.profileservice.spi.ProfileService
10:08:14,713 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Added bean(jboss.j2ee:jar=profileservice-secured.jar,name=SecureProfileService,service=EJB3) to KernelDeployment of: profileservice-secured.jar
10:08:14,714 INFO  [JBossASKernel] installing bean: jboss.j2ee:jar=profileservice-secured.jar,name=SecureDeploymentManager,service=EJB3
10:08:14,714 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   with dependencies:
10:08:14,714 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and demands:
10:08:14,714 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService
10:08:14,714 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and supplies:
10:08:14,714 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jndi:SecureDeploymentManager/remote-org.jboss.deployers.spi.management.deploy.DeploymentManager
10:08:14,714 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  Class:org.jboss.deployers.spi.management.deploy.DeploymentManager
10:08:14,714 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jndi:SecureDeploymentManager/remote
10:08:14,714 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Added bean(jboss.j2ee:jar=profileservice-secured.jar,name=SecureDeploymentManager,service=EJB3) to KernelDeployment of: profileservice-secured.jar
10:08:14,715 INFO  [JBossASKernel] installing bean: jboss.j2ee:jar=profileservice-secured.jar,name=SecureManagementView,service=EJB3
10:08:14,715 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   with dependencies:
10:08:14,715 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and demands:
10:08:14,715 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService
10:08:14,715 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and supplies:
10:08:14,715 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jndi:SecureManagementView/remote-org.jboss.deployers.spi.management.ManagementView
10:08:14,715 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  Class:org.jboss.deployers.spi.management.ManagementView
10:08:14,715 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jndi:SecureManagementView/remote
10:08:14,715 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Added bean(jboss.j2ee:jar=profileservice-secured.jar,name=SecureManagementView,service=EJB3) to KernelDeployment of: profileservice-secured.jar
10:08:14,722 INFO  [EJB3EndpointDeployer] Deploy AbstractBeanMetaData@6cdc5f76{name=jboss.j2ee:jar=profileservice-secured.jar,name=SecureProfileService,service=EJB3_endpoint bean=org.jboss.ejb3.endpoint.deployers.impl.EndpointImpl properties=[container] constructor=null autowireCandidate=true}
10:08:14,723 INFO  [EJB3EndpointDeployer] Deploy AbstractBeanMetaData@240c5895{name=jboss.j2ee:jar=profileservice-secured.jar,name=SecureDeploymentManager,service=EJB3_endpoint bean=org.jboss.ejb3.endpoint.deployers.impl.EndpointImpl properties=[container] constructor=null autowireCandidate=true}
10:08:14,723 INFO  [EJB3EndpointDeployer] Deploy AbstractBeanMetaData@1cfd0695{name=jboss.j2ee:jar=profileservice-secured.jar,name=SecureManagementView,service=EJB3_endpoint bean=org.jboss.ejb3.endpoint.deployers.impl.EndpointImpl properties=[container] constructor=null autowireCandidate=true}
10:08:14,877 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:jar=profileservice-secured.jar,name=SecureDeploymentManager,service=EJB3
10:08:14,887 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: org.jboss.profileservice.ejb.SecureDeploymentManager ejbName: SecureDeploymentManager
10:08:15,010 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

    SecureDeploymentManager/remote - EJB3.x Default Remote Business Interface
    SecureDeploymentManager/remote-org.jboss.deployers.spi.management.deploy.DeploymentManager - EJB3.x Remote Business Interface

10:08:15,055 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:jar=profileservice-secured.jar,name=SecureManagementView,service=EJB3
10:08:15,056 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: org.jboss.profileservice.ejb.SecureManagementView ejbName: SecureManagementView
10:08:15,064 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

    SecureManagementView/remote - EJB3.x Default Remote Business Interface
    SecureManagementView/remote-org.jboss.deployers.spi.management.ManagementView - EJB3.x Remote Business Interface

10:08:15,107 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:jar=profileservice-secured.jar,name=SecureProfileService,service=EJB3
10:08:15,108 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: org.jboss.profileservice.ejb.SecureProfileServiceBean ejbName: SecureProfileService
10:08:15,150 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:

    SecureProfileService/remote - EJB3.x Default Remote Business Interface
    SecureProfileService/remote-org.jboss.profileservice.spi.ProfileService - EJB3.x Remote Business Interface

10:08:15,778 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/admin-console
10:08:15,930 INFO  [config] Initializing Mojarra (1.2_12-b01-FCS) for context '/admin-console'
10:08:19,678 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/
10:08:23,577 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/WebDataViewer
10:08:23,825 INFO  [config] Initializing Mojarra (1.2_12-b01-FCS) for context '/WebDataViewer'
10:08:24,812 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/jmx-console
10:08:25,069 INFO  [Http11Protocol] Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-127.0.0.1-8080
10:08:25,093 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-127.0.0.1-8009
10:08:25,099 INFO  [ServerImpl] JBoss (Microcontainer) [5.1.0.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_5_1_0_GA date=200905221634)] Started in 45s:387ms
```

Snippet from web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: A 404 means that your web address is not pointing to anything in the web server, and there really is not any more that log files can say about that.

Comment: Exact reason i posted a question here. From the logs, it looks like my  url is correct and there should be something coming up - an error at the very least.

Comment: I have never learned to under estimate how frustrating a Java EE container can be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The address `http://localhost:8080/WebDataViewer` just points to the context root of the application, so it will just work if you've a default page defined (such as index.jsp). If you've no default resource for the context root WebDataViewer, you'll have to especify a resource name (a resource can be a servlet, a jsp, jsf ...), for example: `http://localhost:8080/WebDataViewer/myservlet.`

Usually you can look at the resources defined for your application in the WEB-INF/web.xml of your application, for example:

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In your case, according to your web.xml, it seems you're using JSF. So I guess that you should have some xhtml files in the root of your war (or at least in any subdirectory). For example if your war is like:

```
WebDataViewer.war
    |
    |--page.xhtml
    |
    |--WEB-INF
    |     |
    |     |- web.xml
    |     |- ...
    |- ...
```

A valid address would be: `http://localhost:8080/WebDataViewer/page.xhtml`.

Comment: I have that already. I've updated my question with some of my web.xml.

Comment: I once went crazy figuring out a 404 while using Glassfish, it turns out that the URL was ***case sensitive***.  Might be worth being 100% sure that you have the case right.

Comment: Here's the url copied from my browser `http://localhost:8080/WebDataViewer/`. The context matches what's in the logs i've provided

Comment: I've updated the answer, according to the web.xml you've posted. I hope it helps.

Comment: I have index.xhtml at the same level as WEB-INF. `http://localhost:8080/WebDataViewer/` should resolve to `http://localhost:8080/WebDataViewer/index.xhtml` because of the welcome-file in my web.xml. Even if i go directly to `http://localhost:8080/WebDataViewer/index.xhtml` still just 404 error page with no errors in logs.

Comment: It's really strange. Do you have any other file in your war root (a part of the index.html, WEB-INF and META-INF)? Have you checked if you can access those? But notice that the welcome-file-list sets index.html as the welcome page, not index.xhtml!

Comment: DoH!! I didn't notice that until you said that. Now i'm getting a `FacesContext is null` error, but at least it's an error!

Comment: Great! And about the "FacesContext is null" error, could you provide a little bit more information, like some piece of code of the associated bean, and the xhtml that causes the error? But probably that would be another question thread.

Comment: I think i'll leave that to another question. I'll try and narrow it down myself first.